# Missing header in awk output

Tags: awk, gawk, nawk

input:

```
position fst
1 0.6
2 0.8
3 0.9
4 0.3
5 1
```

This gives me a header:

```
awk '{if ($2>=0.7) print $1}' input > output
```

but this doesn't:

```
awk '{if ($2<0.7) print $1}' input > output
```

How come?

Comment: I cannot tell you why without your `input`!

Comment: what do you mean by `header`? Can we have a small sample of your `input`? The former command prints the value in the first column of the line if the second column of that line is >= 0.7, and the other prints the value if its < 0.7. So maybe you don't get anything for the second because all values in column two are less than 0.7.

Comment: For me it prints all $1. I think your numbers are being truncated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always want to print the header then use:

```
awk '{if (NR>1) {if ($2>=0.7) print $1} else print $1}'
awk '{if (NR>1) {if ($2<0.7) print $1} else print $1}'
```

Answer (score 3):

In your second example, `$2<0.7` is interpreted as `"fst"<"0.7"` which is `FALSE`

You can add `NR==1 ||` to always print first line:

```
$ awk 'NR==1 || $2<0.7{print $1}' input
position
1
4
```